# Empty spaces in a List after tokenization

Tags: java, tokenize

I have a list of words and after tokenization, I get some empty spaces in my list which I actually don't want. Suggestions please...

Sample String

```
String str = "3) type an \"l\" in the search field (\"bl\")"+
"4) startHistorySearch()'s previous result contains [\"blah\", \"baaa\", \"bloop\", \"bzzz\"], Satchel filters this down to [\"blah\", \"bloop\"] to match the new \"bl\" search string"+
and so on.....
```

here is the code and output snippet

```
String[] splitString = (EXAMPLE_TEST.split("[\\[\\],\\'\"  \\(\\)\\{\\}\\*\\.]"));
```

Output

```
nsIAutoCompletResult, , no, , Simple, , , , so, the, QI, fails, , historyResult
```

and at some places I see like this...

```
finds, 1, entry, , , blah, , , , search-suggestions, finds, , baaa, , , , bloop, , , , bzzz, , , the, autocompete, menu, shows, these, in, order, with, a, divider, between, , blah, , and, , baaa, , 3, , type, , l, , in, the, search, field, , , bl, , 4, , startHistorySearch, , , s, previous, result, contains, , , blah, , , , baaa, , , , bloop, , , , bzzz, , , , Satchel, filters, this, down, to, , , blah, , , , bloop, , , to, match, the, new, , bl, , search, string5, , nsSearchSuggestions, s, onReadyState, , , change, is, called, with, updated, search,
```

Comment: iterate over it again and remove anything with length zero after a trim.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a `+` to your expression, to not split between two tokens. You can also simplify your expression a bit, you don't have to escape all those characters in a character class:

```
String[] splitString = (EXAMPLE_TEST.split("[\\[\\],'\" (){}*.]+"));
```